# SQL Order By in Custom Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have data in this order

```
Id      Name
----    ------------
6783    Football
6783    Football
4394    Football
4394    Football
1786    Cricket
1786    Cricket
3265    Tennis
3265    Tennis
2601    Hockey
2601    Hockey
9554    Badminton
9554    Badminton
1947    Basketball
1947    Basketball
```

How can I sort this data in this order?

```
Id      Name
----    ------------
6783    Football
4394    Football
1786    Cricket
3265    Tennis
2601    Hockey
9554    Badminton
1947    Basketball
6783    Football
4394    Football
1786    Cricket
3265    Tennis
2601    Hockey
9554    Badminton
1947    Basketball
```

Comment: How do you define said order? There appears to be no logic to it. For example why is Cricket after Football but before Tennis, or why is  4394 after 6783 but before 9554?

Comment: Actually I want to sort same names with different Ids together as you can see in Football case. And also make partition based on same Ids.

Comment: But there's nothing in the sample data you have given us to define that order.  You would, at minimum, needs some kind of ascending value, which your table is missing.

Comment: There is no such order in original table. It is completely random. But I want to sort same names with different Ids together as you can see in Football case. And also make partition based on same Ids.

Comment: Then you can't get the order you want. T be able to get data in an order you need *something* that defines that order. If you have nothing to define that order, you can't get it in that order. Tables are inherently unordered, so without that definition, SQL Server is free to return them in *any* arbitrary order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this requires a big assumption which is that the original sequence is reproducible somehow.  Just by entering those rows into a database without a sequence we would be unable to be guaranteed to reproduce the result.

This code assigns a sequence to the original data.  Using the column o_seq the ORDER BY produces the requested order.

```
drop table if exists dbo.test_table;
go
create table dbo.test_table(
  Id            int not null,
  [Name]            varchar(100) not null);

insert dbo.test_table(Id, [Name]) values
(6783,'Football'),
(6783,'Football'),
(4394,'Football'),
(4394,'Football'),
(1786,'Cricket'),
(1786,'Cricket'),
(3265,'Tennis'),
(3265,'Tennis'),
(2601,'Hockey'),
(2601,'Hockey'),
(9554,'Badminton'),
(9554,'Badminton'),
(1947,'Basketball'),
(1947,'Basketball');

drop table if exists dbo.test_table2;
go
create table dbo.test_table2(
  Id            int not null,
  [Name]        varchar(100) not null,
  o_seq         int);

/* this is not recomended.  I had to visually inspect the rows to make sure this worked */
insert dbo.test_table2 select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) from dbo.test_table t


/* produces the correct sort order */
;with nums_cte as (
    select *, (o_seq-1)%2 s2
    from dbo.test_table2)
select * from nums_cte
order by s2, o_seq;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really an ugly way to do it:

```
Declare @tbl as table(id int, nme varchar(10))

insert into @tbl values(6783,'Football');
insert into @tbl values(6783,'Football');
insert into @tbl values(4394,'Football');
insert into @tbl values(4394,'Football');
insert into @tbl values(1786,'Cricket');
insert into @tbl values(1786,'Cricket');
insert into @tbl values(3265,'Tennis');
insert into @tbl values(3265,'Tennis');
insert into @tbl values(2601,'Hockey');
insert into @tbl values(2601,'Hockey');
insert into @tbl values(9554,'Badminton');
insert into @tbl values(9554,'Badminton');
insert into @tbl values(1947,'Basketball');
insert into @tbl values(1947,'Basketball');

select *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by (Select 0)) as rnk2
into #tmp
from @tbl

select * from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY  id order by (Select 0)) as rnk from #tmp 
) X order by rnk, rnk2
```

Comment: FYI the `SELECT 0` will effectively result in "any arbitrary order", meaning that the query could return a different order every time it runs.

Comment: I used it many times to maintain the original order of the rows, fortunately I have not got arbitrary order till now ;)

Comment: Pure luck then, I'm afraid.

Comment: @AbdulMateen note that this solution has no guarantee to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want one row per id interspersed.  If so:

```
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by id),
         id desc;
```

Comment: This would put `1786` after  `3265` and `2601` not before though, and `9554` would be the first row.

Comment: It partitioned the table as I want, but didn't sort same names with different Ids together as you can see in Football case.